# How to develop an application with ms-access-2016 and make it compatible with previous versions (2007)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

Am using MS Access 2016 to develop an application managing images. But some of my users are still using MS Access 2007 on their computers. And the receive the error "unrecognized database format".

So I would like to know if there is any solution for this. Like making my application compatible for previous versions.

I did some researches for days but not satisfied yet.

Need any help, solution or advice please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Develop using the lowest version that your application will address, here 2007.

A newer version - 2010 and onwards - will run an older with no problems. However, 2007 is 32-bit only, thus - if you use API calls and some users run Access 64-bit - you must take care of that.